# Is there a way to have a function update a layout when it's in an <include> (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, include, drawer

Using Android Studio's built in `Navigation Drawer Activity` several files are created automatically. `content_main` is included automatically in the hello World application and I've changed content main to have some menu item buttons and another include. This include goes to the list_of_items layout.

[image: This is the content_main layout]

My question is, how do I update the list_of_items layout with new information from a seperate class?

[image]

Comment: As the id's are unique within the layouts you can still reference them as though they are in the parent layout.

Comment: I'm using mainactivity.java to run the main screen. I'm using update_list.java to update the list. Is there a way to have one class do the updates, and then go back to mainactivity?

Answer (score 0):

include merges the code at runtime so all it's views and id's will be available to you. you can do whatever needed.
for second point pass value to be updated in new class constructor then implement logic in it's method and return the value  everything from mainactivity